# D3 Accessing max value in 2d array of objects - brushing Y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 stacked area chart where I am trying to re-calculate the Y axis on brushing.  The problem is that when I re-caclulate the max value for the Y axis it is not the combination of all the different layers, it is just the last layer.  For instance if I brushed both the 1/17 and the 1/20 dates I would get 45 as the max Y axis value instead of 95 (50 + 45).  Here is the data:

```
[
  {
     "key": "Failed",
     "vis": "1",
     "values": [
        {
           "date": "2014-01-17T05:00:00.000Z",
           "total": 50
        },
        {
           "date": "2014-01-20T05:00:00.000Z",
           "total": 23
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "key": "Success",
     "vis": "1",
     "values": [
        {
           "date": "2014-01-17T05:00:00.000Z",
           "total": 45
        },
        {
           "date": "2014-01-20T05:00:00.000Z",
           "total": 12
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

Here is some sample code I am working with.  I know that each iteration of the outer loop is wiping out the previous, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataSeries.length; i++) {
    if(dataSeries[i]['vis'] === "1") {

        dataFiltered = dataSeries[i]['values'].filter(function(d) {

            if((d.date >= main_x.domain()[0]) && (d.date <= main_x.domain()[1])) {

                // this is just returning the biggest total in the date range from the last layer (i.e.: 'Failed'),
                // not the greatest of all the layers for that day                       
                return yValue(d);   
            }                           
        });
    }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goodspeedj/eguE5/) - if you brush over a range of dates the Y axis max will not be correct and the top of the chart will be cut off.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clobbering `dataFiltered` in each iteration of `dataSeries`.  In `dataSeries` you have an element for each level in your stack, so this means that `dataFiltered` will only ever contain values from the last element.

But even if you fix that problem there is still something odd with the way you're setting up the domain of the y scale:

```
main_y.domain([0, d3.sum(dataFiltered.map(function(d) { return d.total; }))]);
```

This is setting the upper value of the domain to be the summed total of all of the data points in your brushed range.  What you probably actually want is the maximum fully stacked height within the range.

You can do something like this:

```
var dataFiltered = dataSeries.map(function(series) {
    return series.values.filter(function(d) {
        if((d.date >= main_x.domain()[0]) && (d.date <= main_x.domain()[1])) {
            return yValue(d);
        }
    });
});
```

At this point `dataFiltered` will look just like `dataSeries` except it should only contain data points from the brushed range.

Now you'll need to turn it inside out so that the data points are oriented in terms of stacks, not in terms of series:

```
var dataStackSums = {};
dataFiltered.forEach(function(series) {
    series.values.forEach(function(d) {
        if (!dataStackSums[d.date]) { dataStackSums[d.date] = 0; }
        dataStackSums[d.date] += d.total;
    });
});
```

At this point `dataStackSums` contains a property for every X axis value (date) with a value representing the summed Y axis for that stack.  From here you just need to determine the max stack:

```
var max = 0;
Object.keys(dataStackSums).forEach(function(key) {
    max = Math.max(max, dataStackSums[key]);
});
```

Then you can set up the domain:

```
main_y.domain([0, max]);
```

Note that I broke out these steps for clarity but you could collapse the filtering and the stack-orienting into one step for efficiency.

Comment: Thank you - that worked great (with one minor edit that I made to the post).